# Edited: Mongoose - How can I only allow the owner to update current document?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

EDITED: 
**Summary**

For people to update a specific project, the userId which is already saved when users create a project, must match their current user id. The current user is saved in the req.users, so it can be accessed after a user has logged in.

Inside my Mongoose Project Schema I have the following

```
const projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema(

{

name: String,

description: String,

userId: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,

}

...
```

Which if queried on find() it will return:

```
{
_id: 213213156,
name: "Project1",
description: "A brief description"
userId: 3131132, //this is the user that created this project
}
```

```
//I have set this router so that is protected, so users need to login.

Routing:

router
.route("/:projectId")
.get(projectsController.getProject)
.patch(authController.protect, projectsController.updateProject);
```

**How it works?**

Everytime I create a project I assign the userId that the current user which is logged in has.

**What have I tried?**

I have tried querying using Model.find(), obtaining the userId and then generating an if statement.

I also tried doing some pre middlewares, but I think I am not using them correctly.

**What I want to do?**

I want to be able to update a project ONLY if its auth _id (the current user id which is stored in the req.users) matches projects userId field -- which is already saved in that project.

Ex.

```
// I want to be able to access the userId without having to query find() -- because then I would have to perform 2 queries: find() and then findByIdAndUpdate
if(userId !== req.user.id) {
return new Error(msg)
}
```

Comment: Can you post please sample data and explain with steps... I'm afraid not only me is confused

Comment: Ok. I will edit the post to make it clearer

Comment: You need something like: `Model.updateOne({userId:req.users._id}, {your_project})`?

Comment: I can use findByIdAndUpdate and updateOne, but the idea is that only the Project Owner which is the userId can be able to update it... That is why i want to first authenticate that the model's userId matches the id of that user which is saved in the login token.

Comment: @Valijon added more information and also changed title.

Comment: If you run [Model.findByIdAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)({userId:req.users._id}, your_project)` updates only if `userId` exists. If it doesn't resolve your question, recommend share full code and point where you would like to change. Check how this user describes his [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60523655/mongodb-select-and-update-with-complicated-conditions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> findOneById accepts multiple conditions, so what you can do is first
>   search for the _id you want to modify and in the second condition,
>   userId must match the current user.

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate({ 
    _id: req.params.projectId, 
    userId: req.user.id 
    }, ...
```